# RegEx escape function in R

Tags: regex, r, escaping

In a R script, I'd need to create a RegEx that contains strings that may have special characters. So, I should first escape those strings and then use them in the RegEx object.

```
pattern <- regex(paste('\\W', str, '\\W', sep = ''));
```

In this example, `str` should be fixed. So, I'd need a function that returns escaped form of its input. For example `'c++'` -> `'c\\+\\+'`

Comment: sounds interesting, what did you come up with?

Comment: Would this not be solved by setting the `fixed` argument to `TRUE` in many of the base R regex functions? E.g. `sub("c++", "REPLACED", "c++", fixed = TRUE) == sub("c\\+\\+", "REPLACED", "c++")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to escape only 12 character, so a conditional regular expression including those should do the trick -- for example:

```
> gsub('(\\\\^|\\$|\\.|\\||\\?|\\*|\\+|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\{)', '\\\\\\1', 'C++')
[1] "C\\+\\+"
```

Or you could build that regular expression from the list of special chars if you do not like the plethora of manual backslashes above -- such as:

```
> paste0('(', paste0('\\', strsplit('\\^$.|?*+()[{', '')[[1]], collapse = '|'), ')')
[1] "(\\\\|\\^|\\$|\\.|\\||\\?|\\*|\\+|\\(|\\)|\\[|\\{)"
```